# Problem about wrapping lstlisting environment into another environment with etoolbox

Tags: listings, environments, etoolbox

In the following **MWE**, I tried to wrap an `lstlisting` environment(`testlst`) into another environment(`test`) by the pairs of macros `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` that come from the package `etoolbox`.

Though it runs without error, both `\vrule` in the code do not work(draw vertical lines). Why?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{listings,xparse,etoolbox}

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
% -------------------------
\newenvironment{test}[1]
{\begin{minipage}{#1}}
{\end{minipage}}
% -------------------------
\lstnewenvironment{testlst}[2][]
{
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{testlst}{\vrule\begin{test}{#2}}
  \lstset{#1}  
}
{
  \AfterEndEnvironment{test}{\end{minipage}\vrule}
}
% -------------------------
% Test:
\begin{testlst}[numbers=left]{5in}
  \rule{2in}{10pt}
\end{testlst}
% -------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: What effect do you want from those two `\vrule`? PS: `listings` has frame options.

Comment: I want `\vrule` to typeset a vertical line. Here it is only for example to see how `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` work with `lstlisting` environment. It can be replaced by any other macros. It's not my intension to draw a frame.

Comment: The macros `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` are designed to be used after (therefore outside) the definition of the environment to be modified.

Comment: So my `\vrule` is outside of `testlst`. Why does it not draw a vline outside of  `testlst`?

Comment: One: you first define an environment and then declare `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment`. Two: why would you use them since you can just add the commands in the definition of the environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't going to work. You first define an environment and then, perhaps, declare `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment`.

But there's no need to, because *you* are defining the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstnewenvironment{testlst}[2][]
 {
  \trivlist\item\relax\vrule\minipage{#2}
  \lstset{#1}
 }
 {
  \endminipage\vrule\endtrivlist
 }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{testlst}[numbers=left]{5in}
  \rule{2in}{10pt}
  \rule{2in}{10pt}
  \rule{2in}{10pt}
\end{testlst}
\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to use the “naked” form of environments, because `lstnewenvironment` is a kind of verbatim.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks！ And I don't understand the meaning of `\trivlist\item\relax`. Would you say more about it?

Comment: @lyl That's the customary way to get vertical space top and bottom.

Comment: And another question. You can see that the package `xparse` is input in my code.  I want `testlst` env to have two optional arguments like xparse 's `O{}G{}` . I don't konw how to achieve this in `\lstnewenvironment`.

Comment: @lyl You can't. And `G` argument type is deprecated anyway.